# PDO update database field with current value + new value

Tags: php, pdo, sql-update, echo

I have the following code:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');

$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE channelbro_rss SET links = ? WHERE channel = ?");
$statement->execute(array($links_new, $channel));
```

but how do I set `$links_new` to the current value of `links` from the database, plus a new value?

***For example:***

The value of `links` in the database is `test`. Now first of all I want to echo this value and then update the value of `links` to the current value (`test`) plus another variable (separated by commas). E.g.: Update `links` to `test, new`. And if I do this whole thing again, it will update it to `test, new, hello` (The new value is always `$new`).

Comment: do something like `links = CONCAT(links,', ',?)` to merge/concat while update, with comma as seperator. For `Now first of all I want to echo this value` you need a second `SELECT` query

Comment: Are you sure that this should not rather be properly normalized in the first place …?

Comment: You should probably use a different table to store these texts one per row and link that table to your `channelbro_rss`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simpler to add the value you wish to amend the old value by like this.

the `concat()` function will as its name suggests concatenate the new string onto the existing contents of the column.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=web190_db8', 'web190_8', 'password');

// If you want to see the value of links before you amend it
// as your requested, then you will have to get it as a seperate
// SELECT query

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT links FROM channelbro_rss WHERE channel = ?");
$stmt->execute( array($channel) );
$old_links = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);

echo $old_links;

$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE channelbro_rss SET links = concat(links, ?) WHERE channel = ?");

$concat_text = ', new';
$statement->execute(array($concat_text, $channel));


// If you want to see the value of links AFTER you amend it
// then you will have to get it as a seperate SELECT query also

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT links FROM channelbro_rss WHERE channel = ?");
$stmt->execute( array($channel) );
$old_links = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);

echo $old_links;
```

Comment: You have to do a `SELECT` query if you want to look at the contents of any column, an `UPDATE` will not return anything other that a status i.e. success or failure of the UPDATE query

Comment: See amended answer which now contains some code to get the current value of `links` before you update it

Comment: If its because I added the `// fetch current value of links` code. I was expressly asked for that by the person asking the question

Comment: It's because Dipanwita Kundu / JustOnUnderMillions  gave the right answer and yours were wrong. And now you are getting all the upvotes after whining to your friends. Fair.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I did no whining to any friends just for the sake of fact

Comment: @YourCommonSense I admit that on review there is a little room for interpretation in the OP's statement `plus another variable (seperated by commas)`

Answer (score 3):

Update your query like this:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE channelbro_rss SET links = concat(links, ? ) WHERE channel = ?");
```

Comment: Why should the OP "update the query like this"?  A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Mysql** `CONCAT` function; This is what is said about it in

[the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

:

> CONCAT(str1,str2,...)
>
> Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments. May
>   have one or more arguments. If all arguments are nonbinary strings,
>   the result is a nonbinary string. If the arguments include any binary
>   strings, the result is a binary string. A numeric argument is
>   converted to its equivalent nonbinary string form.

This is the query string you are looking for :

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web190_db8', 'web190_8', 'password');

$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE channelbro_rss SET links = CONCAT(links,', ', ?)  WHERE channel = ?");# result: test, new, hello
$statement->execute(array($links_new, $channel));
```

There is also `CONCAT_WS(separator,str1,str2,...)` . Check mysql documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) for further infos.

Good luck

Comment: Their answer result in : testnewhello and that's not what is asked and mine is : test, new, hello

Comment: This is the change I made : CONCAT(links,', ', ?)

Comment: Ok, nvm me then. I thought you just gave the exact same answer

Comment: If you notice `$concat_text = ',new,hello';`.... How is that not what was requested ??????????

Comment: Check this line in question : **And if I do this hole thing again it will update it to test, new, hello**

Comment: He's talking about if you `concat` it without the `,` you get testnewhello, but the *requested* was with the `,` inbetween

Comment: I put the commas in the text I was concatenating. What the difference ??????? Same result !!!!!!!!

Comment: Here is an example from **MYSQL** doc : CONCAT('My', 'S', 'QL');// output : 'MySQL'

Comment: Ok I will play `SELECT CONCAT('test', ', new, hello');` == `test, new, hello`

Comment: And one  thing to consider also is that you don't know the text in advance, so every time would have to insert the comma  in text manually and that's a lot of work why not do it in one go

Comment: And your answer does not address this part of the question ___Now first of all I want to echo this value and then update the value of links to the current value (test) plus another variable (seperated by commas)___ Should I therefore downvote your answer ?????

Comment: Simple `Select ` to first get the current value isn't that difficult; And It's up to you to downvote. That doesn't matter